# AspNet Core WebAPI & UWP

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core, uwp, owin

Is it possible to self-host an Asp.net Core 2 WebAPI project in a UWP application? (like we can, for example do with SignalR)
And if it is, how do I achieve this goal?

Comment: The short answer is impossible, you may check the history on this github issue [Support for ASP.Net core functionality in UWP project #2116](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/2116).

Comment: I was not searching for a quick answer, i was wondering if someone has done it before and knows if it is possible technically.

Comment: If you like this feature, you could vote here [Support for Asp.Net Core running on UWP as Windows IoT Core Background Task](https://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general-asp-net/suggestions/32626766-support-for-asp-net-core-running-on-uwp-as-windows)

Comment: Voting is closed even if some devs did show interest in this feature. I guess it's all in MS's hands right now